# Show that if K is a non-zero ideal of Z/mZ,

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Show that if K is a non-zero ideal of Z/mZ, then K is the principal idea.

Please help!

Comment: Can you share what you've tried, and explain what you're having trouble with?

Comment: It might help you to use the fact that ideals and subgroups of $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$ are the same thing. Prove it for subgroups, and you’re almost done.

Comment: Have you proved the corresponding statement for $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: No, I have not.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a$ be the smallest positive integer in the set $B = \{b \in \mathbb{N} : b+m\mathbb{Z} \in K\}$. Let $[c] = c+ m\mathbb{Z}$ be any  element of $K$ (where c is taken to be the minimal positive representation). By definition of $a$ this means that $a < c$.

Assume that $a$ does not divide $c$. Perform the division algorithm to obtain $q,r$ such that $c = aq+r$ and $ 0 <r <a$. Then

$$[r] = r+m\mathbb{Z} = c-aq + m\mathbb{Z} \in K$$

This contradicts the minimality of $a$ as now $r$ is a smaller integer in $B$. Thus $a$ must divide $c$ and we get $K \subset ([a])$ (the ideal generated by the residues class of $a$).

Clearly $([a]) \subset K$ and we get the equality we wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Given a ring $R$ and an ideal $I\subseteq R$, then any ideal of $R/I$ is of the form $J/I$ where $J$ is an ideal of $R$ *containing* $I$ and $J/I=\{x+I:x\in J\}$.

Now let's consider your question with $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $I=m\mathbb{Z}$. If $K$ is a nonzero ideal of $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}=R/I$ then we need only find ideals $J\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ that contain $I=m\mathbb{Z}$. Recall that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID, and an ideal $J=d\mathbb{Z}$ contains $m\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $d$ divides $m$. Thus, $$K=d\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}=\{nd+m\mathbb{Z}:n\in \mathbb{Z}\}=\{n(d+m\mathbb{Z}):n\in \mathbb{Z}\}=(\overline{d})$$ for some proper divisor $d$ of $m$ and hence, $K$ is principal.